# Redirect Tomcat 9 to FQDN

Tags: tomcat, redirect, fqdn

i don't find an helpful awnser for my problem.

I have a Tomcat 9 with an "intranet website" and it works with https. Https works with the fqdn only.

Currently i have a redirect from http to https. (web.xml - security-constraint)

http://host to https://host work's with "certificate error - unsecure website".

With the Fqdn

http://host.v654.com to https://host.v654.com work's fine "without certicate error"

So i would like to redirect the "normal urls"

http://host to http://host.v654.com

and

https://host to https://host.v654.com

Thank You for help

Marcus

Comment: If you have a certificate issued for `correct.example.com` only, a redirect from `https://wrong.example.com` to `https://correct.example.com` would not work, because a browser will signal a certificate error **before** it even sends the request.

Comment: Currently i have a redirect from http to https

Comment: That redirect should redirect from `http://wrong.example.com` to `https://correct.example.com`. If it doesn't work as expected, can you explain (by editing your question) how did you configure the redirect (there are many ways).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thank You for comment. I have edit my question. I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already remarked in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174106/redirect-tomcat-9-to-fqdn?noredirect=1#comment120490616_68174106), if you type `https://host` in your browser, you'll get a certificate error **before** your browser sends any request to Tomcat: your browser does not trust the server, why should it trust the redirect sent by the server?

However you can modify the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in such a way that `http://host` is redirected to `https://host.example.com`, by modifying the `proxyName` i `redirectPort` on your connector:

```xml
<Connector port="80"
           proxyName="host.example.com"
           redirectPort="443"
           ...
           />
```

The `proxyName` attribute fixes the hostname used in all URLs generated by Tomcat. By default the hostname provided by the HTTP client is used.

Comment: Thank you very much, Piotr. As expected `https://host` with "certificate error" doesn't work, but when i type `http://host` the redirect to `https://host.v654.com` works perfectly now.